# How to import a jar in a java file

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I'm totally new to clojure and leiningen, all I want to do is write some java code that will use this library https://github.com/nathanmarz/dfs-datastores

Here is what I did :

1. Created a new leiningen project.
2. Added `[com.backtype/dfs-datastores "1.3.6"]` to my `:dependencies` ( I checked my `.m2/repository/com/backtype/dfs-datastores/1.3.6` and there are some jar files there)
3. Created a new .java file in the main project directory with some code.

Now how can I use the dfs-datastores code inside my `.java` file ?

Comment: You have a jar file with Java runtime code in it, and you want to call it from a Java program. Why would Leiningen need to be further involved? Your project should be ant or sbt or maven or some other Java-compatible build tool - even command line Java. Leiningen is just for Clojure/Clojurescript source code.

Comment: I think you probably want to do `lein uberjar` without your Java file, and then put the uberjar file in target/ into your classpath for the Java file.